# Image pixcel to Real world position calculation

Tags: opencv, math, emgucv

How to calculate real world location from image pixels when having below information.
I went through Key hole camera model and few openCV functionalities but confused where to fit these values exactly.

1. Camera position as shown below

[image]

2. Camera Intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients  as shown below

[image]

3. Rotation information

[image]

Comment: you can only for each pixel construct the ray of 3d rwal world points that project to the pixel

Comment: Here my image is a photo taken from a camera mounted on top of the vehicle. Projecting ray will not works for me.

Comment: it's not a real projection in the scene, it is a virtual path on which a pixel can lie in the real world. Just from a 2D image you can't tell the 3D point, since projection (from scene to camera image)  will project ALL 3D positions on that ray to a single pixel position. During capturing a 2D image you basically lose the 3D information, so you cant reconstruct it (without additional information).